# Returning to same view still get old view data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am returning to same view after getting few changes.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/next/{nextNo}")
public ModelAndView next(@PathVariable("nextNo") int nextNo,
        ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println(nextNo);
        List<Employee> listEmp = empService.findAllEmployees();
        RosterData data = new RosterData();
        data.setListEmployee(listEmp);
        data.setDays(UtilClass.getDays(nextNo));
        data.setCurrentWeek(UtilClass.getCurrrentWeek(nextNo));
        List<Roster> shiftList = rosterService.findAllShift();
        data.setRoster(shiftList);
        model.addAttribute("employees", data);
        return new ModelAndView("roster");
}
```

I am already on roster view and calling the above controller code. But my view is not updating with new data, When I debug and in log I am getting updated data. In browser I am getting always old data. The page is not loading again, i tried with an alert on document.ready function. 
Please help

Comment: Do you really need that constructor? The last argument `RosterDomain()` is the model object right? Maybe you should pass the `model` object (which you are adding atribute `"employees"` to) to the `ModelAndView` constructor? Or just use the constructor with the view name only, so `return new ModelAndView("roster")`.

Comment: Yes, @wdc clearly points out what's wrong : you add data to a model but finally returns a different, empty, model `new RosterDomain()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are setting the attribute `"employees"` to one model object, and setting another model object (`RosterDomain`) as the third parameter in `ModelAndView("roster","roster",new RosterDomain());` constructor. You can either

1. Pass the same model object you are setting attribute to to the current constructor, so replace `return new ModelAndView("roster","roster",new RosterDomain());` with `return new ModelAndView("roster","roster",model);`

or even better (recommended)

2. Use different constructor and set the model to be the one you are setting the `"employees"` attribute to. So `return new ModelAndView("roster");` and the model you are using will be automatically "attached" to `ModelAndView`.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion and still getting the same behavior, I have updated the question with latest code.

Comment: @GanesanS Can you also post the header of the function (with all the arguments)?

Comment: @GanesanS that seems fine, data should be sent to the view. Maybe you are incorrectly accessing data on the view... Try adding something simple to the model, for example model.addAttribute("foo","bar"); and try to read display it to the view.

Comment: In jsp side its fine I guess. The JSP is not reloading, I have added an alert msg. First time its loading. When I call the above request mapping, the alert msg is not coming.